# SSL doesn't work after update httpd in centos

Tags: apache, ssl, httpd.conf

I've wrongly launched the command

```
sudo yum install httpd
```

in the command line of a server of mine.
SInce httpd was already installed, this command have reinstalled/updated *httpd* but after that I was no more able to start httpd: launching the command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

I received the error:

> Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443
>   no listening sockets available, shutting down

so looking deeper in the configuration files I saw that the

```
Listen 443
```

was both in the conf/httpd.conf and in conf.d/ssl.conf.
Commenting one of them the httpd service starts correctly but seems that SSL is not working properly because if I access to some pages I know are protected under SSL i receive an

> 404 Not found

Someone knows which configuration coudl I have corrupted with that update?
How can I fix it?

Comment: a 404 indicates SSL is working perfectly, because SSL has already happened for you to get any actual http response. What you seem to have a wrong documentroot, or wrong configuration. Check your virtualhosts with "apachectl -S" and make sure your virtualhosts configurations are being loaded correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.
There were two _VirtualHost *default:443* (one coming from httpd.conf and one coming from ssl.conf).

Removing one of them (I suggest removing the *httpd.conf*'s one to leave all the ssl configurations in ssl.conf file) everything restarted working properly.